# Trying to initialize a multidimensional vector in R

Tags: r, vector, initialization

I am using knn to make estimates of random data, and I am choosing different k's from a vector. Each knn returns a vector of length 200, and I have 13 k's, so I need a 13x200 vector initialized before the for loop. I want to do something like

```
knn_train <- rep(0,1000)
```

But for a multidimensional vector.

Here is my code:

```
library(class)
library(MASS)
#List of k's for use in knn
k <- c(1,4,7,10,13,16,30,45,60,80,100,150,200)
#Generate identity matrix for sigmas 
sigma <- diag(2)
# Class 1
mu_green <- c(-.5,.5)
green_train <- mvrnorm(100, mu_green,sigma)
green_test <-  mvrnorm(100, mu_green,sigma)
#Class 0
mu_red <-c(-.2,.6)
red_train<- mvrnorm(100, mu_red,sigma)
red_test<- mvrnorm(100, mu_red,sigma)
#Bind test and train data
train <- rbind(green_train,red_train)
test <- rbind(green_test,red_test)
cl <- rbind(c(rep(1,100),rep(0,100)))


for(i in 1:length(k))
{
  #Train into train then train into test
  knn_train[i] = knn(train,train,cl,k[i],prob=TRUE)
  knn_test[i] = knn(train,test,cl,k[i],prob=TRUE)
  #First 100 are class 1, second 100 are class 2
  train_err[i]<- 100-sum(table(knn_train[i][1:100]))+sum(table(knn[i][100:200]))
  test_err[i]<- 100-sum(table(knn_test[i][1:100]))+sum(table(knn[i][100:200]))
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you are avoiding using a matrix?  The 'matrix' function can initialize a structure like that quite quickly with something like: `matrix(nrow=13, ncol=200)`

Comment: I tried that. Got some errors I do not understand, along with the same warnings. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to initialize a "multidimensional vector" is to create a matrix-object:

```
 knn_train <- matrix(NA, nrow=1000, ncol=13)
```

If you want to populate values then:

```
 knn_train[ , i] <- # 13 element vector
```

Comment: I was apparently writing the same idea in the comments while DWin was writing it up as an answer.  A matrix is probably your quickly solution, and if you want to initialize it with zeros (as in your example), just enter a zero as your first argument, like so: `matrix(0, nrow=13, ncol=200)`

Comment: Warnings:Warning messages:
1: In knn_train[i] = knn(train, train, cl, k[i], prob = TRUE) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In knn_test[i] = knn(train, test, cl, k[i], prob = TRUE) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Errors: Error in knn[i] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In knn_train[i] = knn(train, train, cl, k[i], prob = TRUE) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In knn_test[i] = knn(train, test, cl, k[i], prob = TRUE) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Comment: Please notice that I typed `knn_train[ , i]`  Not ... `knn_train[i]`.